# Email Newsletters

Tags: bulk-email

I want to send Newsletters to my clients and customers. I tried out a shared hosting account but it was blocked cause of sending about 5000 mails in a day. I then checked various sites that offers this newsletter options but they charge too high, even over 100$ p.m.. Is there an alternate solution. Should I go for a dedicated IP with a small hosting pack? Will that work?